# Read Dependencies from File in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

MSBuild is great at detecting when a given file needs to be re-built because it has changed. Is there any chance it can read the file's content to determine what else it depends on? (I'm thinking `// references` or `using` or `@import` statements).

I have a functional build target for less files (a handy way to re-use a NancyFX static resource convention builder I wrote). But when I change a file upstream from the file I'm actually interested in, nothing happens because MSBuild doesn't know about the dependency.

Can you specify more complex dependencies like that in MSBuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of input files to process, and a related list of dependant files such as this item definition:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <XFiles>
    <OutputFile>$(OutDir)%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).xprocessed</OutputFile>
    <Dependency>%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)-SupportFile.xdep</Dependency>
  </XFiles>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

You can specify a dependency on files a target will output in the header of the target like so:

```
<Target Name="ProcessXFilesAndDependencies"
        Inputs="@(XFiles);@(XFiles->'%(Dependency)')"
        Outputs="@(XFiles->'%(OutputFile)')">

  <!-- process stuff -->

</Target>
```

This will take into account the state of the files and the dependant files for your builds.

If I am not mistaken, setting up your target in this manner has the effect of causing it to be evaluated in all cases. Since there is no 1:1 relationship between input and output files (there will always be fewer output files) MSBuild cannot skip this target. This will cause a small overhead for all your builds, but is usually negligible.

Comment: Ok, but having MSbuild automatically produce such a definition group based on file contents?

Comment: Of course, I should have addressed the question you asked specifically rather than dive straight into related details. If you want it to be dynamic like that you would have to create a target that would procure the dependent items based on file contents yourself. Chain the dependency procurement target in front of the processing target using DependsOnTargets. Using ReadLinesFromFile might be exactly the ticket (coupled with some scripting of course).

Comment: I already had custom tasks that helped with compilation and did some of it's own dependency sniffing. I refactored a bit, exposed it as a task, and made the target depend on another target that generated the dependencies dynamically. You set me off down the right track, thanks.